# Android Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP AND Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that I have running a media player and I want to resume the activity from my apps home activity.

I can successfully do this by adding the following flags to the startActivity Call:

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I am worried that this is not an ideal way to do things since it took me a long time to find it. It made me think that no one uses it very much.

Are there any pitfalls to using this method?

Comment: Did you go for it? Did you discover any pitfalls?

Comment: Having Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP on main activity is dangerous .. it might lead to some limits by time .. i.e. any time you lunch app again by pressing icon .. it will clear all activities above mainAcitivity without even calling onDestroy ..

Answer (score 27):

**I know that this question is quite older and may you have solved your problem and may be travelled to mars and back in those years.But just to make things clear for the people coming here and looking for an explanation:**

### According to Official Documentation:

> **If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.**

- Suppose you have BackStack of `A-B-C-D` and You have launched
  another intent Starting `Activity A` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`
  at this point what android will be do is Simply Clear All the
  Activities on the Top of `Activity A`, means now your BackStack Will
  Look like-> `A` (yes that's it because you have cleared all the
  activities on top of it).
- And In Second Scenario Suppose You have the same BackStack A-B-C-D
  and you launched an Intent Starting Activity A with
  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, now your BackStack will look like-> 
  A-B-C-D-A (Confused? Don't Worry Next Example Will Clear All Your
  Confusions)
- Third Scenario, We start with the same BackStack `A-B-C-D` and We
  will launch an Intent Starting `Activity D` with
  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, now our BackStack will look like->
  `A-B-C-D` (Yes the BackStack remains in the Same Order because our
  FLAG prohibits the launch Same Activity If it is the Currently on Top
  of the Stack and Showing on the User screen.
- Last Scenario, We start with our same BackStack `A-B-C-D` and We will
  launch an Intent Starting `Activity D` but this time with no FLAGS,
  now our BackStack will look like-> `A-B-C-D-D`.

> Got it? `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is only useful When you are
>   starting the Same Activity Which is Currently Showing On the Screen
>   and You want to prohibit the launch new Instance of the Existing Activity.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Good one Shubham

Answer (score 13):

Just to make sure I understand your question correctly: Say your activity stack is something like A -> B -> C, and now from C you want to clear the stack and get back to A.

If this is what you want, then those intent flags are correct and should work as expected, as per the [Android-developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FL).