# Cannot set both FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in one intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-stack

I'm using flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to go back to my previous "standard" activity. I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to prevent re-creating a new instance. But what I found is that the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is neglected and the activity is finished and re-created.

- Here is what I found in docs. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP): It says that you can add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` when using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to prevent "finish - recreate".
- Here is another doc. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/reference/android/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks):

  > Note: If the launch mode of the designated activity is "standard", it too is removed from the stack and a new instance is launched in its place to handle the incoming intent. That's because a new instance is always created for a new intent when the launch mode is "standard".

Did I misunderstand the first doc?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation suggests that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is all you need to set. But you actually HAVE to set both to prevent the activity from being created again.

This did the trick in my case: (Main being the activity that I wanted to return to)

```
  Intent tabIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
  tabIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(tabIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one could be helpful: [Android Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP AND Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217942/android-intent-flag-activity-single-top-and-intent-flag-activity-clear-top)

Comment: Thanks Moss. I think I have read that post already, but it didn't help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)